# Is the function $f(x)=\frac{\sin(\sin{(x)}+x)}{2+\cos{(\lvert x\rvert}+\cos{(x)})}$ monotonic and/or periodic?

Tags: calculus, periodic-functions, monotone-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(\sin{(x)}+x)}{2+\cos{(\lvert x\rvert}+\cos{(x)})}$$

I am having trouble showing whether or not this function is monotonic and/or periodic.

**Monotonic:** The function is only monotonic if it is entirely non-increasing or entirely non-decreasing.

1. Monotonically increasing: $\forall x,y$ such that $x\le y$ it follows that  $f(x) \le f(y)$. Choose $x=\pi,y=\frac{3\pi}{2}$: $$\implies f(\pi)=\frac{\sin{(\sin{\pi}+\pi)}}{2+\cos{(\pi+\cos{\pi}})}=\frac{\cos{1}}{2}
    \\f(\frac{3\pi}{2})=\frac{\sin{(\sin{\frac{3 \pi}{2}}+\frac{3\pi}{2})}}{2+\cos(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\cos{\frac{3\pi}{2}})}=\frac{-\cos{1}}{2} \\ \frac{\cos{1}}{2} > -\frac{\cos{1}}{2} \implies \text{not monotonically increasing}$$
2. Monotonically decreasing $\forall x,y$ such that $x \le y$ it follows that $f(x) \ge f(y)$. Choose  $x=0, y=\frac{\pi}{2}$:

$$\implies f(0)=0 \\ f(\frac{\pi}{2})=\frac{\sin{(\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\frac{\pi}{2})}}{2+\cos{(\frac{\pi}{2}+\cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}})}=\frac{\cos{1}}{2} \\ 0 < \frac{\cos{1}}{2} \implies \text{not monotonically decreasing}$$

> Is it possible to argue this way? Am I getting the definitions for
>   monotonicity right?

**Periodic:** This is where I am less sure and quite confused. I know that a function $f$ is periodic if $f(x+T)=f(x)$. I know that $\sin{(x)}$ and $\cos{(x)}$ are $2 \pi$ periodic functions so I my attempt was to just plug in $f(x+2 \pi)$ and see where it leads me.

$$\implies f(x+2 \pi)=\frac{\sin(\sin{(x+2 \pi)}+2 \pi)}{2+\cos{(\lvert x+2 \pi\rvert}+\cos{(x+2 \pi)})}=\frac{\sin{x}}{2+\cos{(\lvert x+2\pi\rvert+\cos{x})}}$$

> If $x \ge 0$ I get the desired solution and $f(x+2 \pi)=f(x)$.
>   However, for negative $x$, $\lvert x+2 \pi \rvert \not=x+2 \pi$. So I
>   cannot show periodicity for all negative $x$. How can I resolve this?
>   Can a function be periodic for positive $x$ and not for negative?

Comment: First of all, this is not Real Analysis. That tag is getting abused way too much. Secondly, the exact same question was asked some days ago. I updated the tags to fit the post.

Comment: @Rebellos The same questions was NOT asked a few days ago because a few days ago I asked if the infimum and supremum could be obtained analytically to which the answer in a comment was "no" so I decided to delete it. This question refers to the same function but I am asking about monotonicity and periodicity. I would appreciate it if you could change that part of the comment. Otherwise, people are just going to look at the comment and assume this is a duplicate. Sorry about the tags. I never know which ones to use.

Comment: Note that $f(x) = -f(-x)$, so periodicity on the interval $[0, \infty)$ implies periodicity on the interval $(-\infty, 0]$. Of course, a function could be periodic for positive and negative $x$ separately but not periodic overall.

Comment: @ConnorHarris Thanks for your comment. Building on your answer, can we now say that the function is periodic even though it has a different periodicity on $[0, \infty)$ and $(-\infty.0]?$

Comment: @Nullspace that's a matter of the precise definition of periodicity that you were handed (I assume this is for some sort of school assignment).